How is a branch-and-bound tree's size estimated in solvers that display it?
I was pleasantly surprised that HiGHS is able to display what I believe is an estimation of the Branch & Bound tree size and what fraction of the nodes are explored. See the following for such display (in column | B&B Tree |, 0.08% explored in the early seconds):
        Nodes      |    B&B Tree     |            Objective Bounds              |  Dynamic Constraints |       Work
     Proc. InQueue |  Leaves   Expl. | BestBound       BestSol              Gap |   Cuts   InLp Confl. | LpIters     Time

         0       0         0   0.00%   66075.262993    -inf                 inf        0      0      0         0     0.2s
         0       0         0   0.00%   26978.646938    -inf                 inf        0      0      5      1536     0.3s
 L       0       0         0   0.00%   26006.74964     22151.394607      17.40%     5880    827    212      8370     4.3s
 L       0       0         0   0.00%   26006.74964     25869.934363       0.53%     5880    827    212     10155     5.5s

0.6% inactive integer columns, restarting
Model after restart has 3806 rows, 4003 cols (4003 bin., 0 int., 0 impl., 0 cont.), and 14523 nonzeros

         0       0         0   0.00%   26006.700177    25869.934363       0.53%      526      0      0     11222     5.8s
         0       0         0   0.00%   26006.700112    25869.934363       0.53%      526    376     11     13204     6.0s
        42       0         1   0.00%   26005.308277    25869.934363       0.52%     2063    404     18     23796    15.8s
        76       2        12   0.00%   26005.308277    25869.934363       0.52%     2086    404     94     32828    20.8s
       122      75        23   0.00%   26004.166575    25869.934363       0.52%     3200    520    846     45646    30.8s
       144      93        23   0.00%   26004.166575    25869.934363       0.52%     3428    497    874     51768    37.0s
       175     118        23   0.00%   26004.166575    25869.934363       0.52%     3441    449    974     59514    43.6s
       222     123        36   0.00%   26004.166575    25869.934363       0.52%     3435    451   1370     69699    49.7s
       272     126        58   0.00%   26004.166575    25869.934363       0.52%     3505    451   2254     78107    54.8s
       289     141        63   0.00%   26004.166575    25869.934363       0.52%     3500    453   2463     83846    59.9s
       316     156        64   0.00%   26004.166575    25869.934363       0.52%     3527    445   2501     89684    66.3s
       377     158        80   0.00%   26004.166575    25869.934363       0.52%     3564    445   2826     98195    71.5s
       414     173        91   0.05%   26004.166575    25869.934363       0.52%     3547    455   3039    103639    76.9s
       442     181        96   0.08%   26004.146514    25869.934363       0.52%     3233    461   3095    109178    82.2s
       529     203       120   0.08%   26004.146514    25869.934363       0.52%     3236    446   3555    116491    88.3s
       604     204       143   0.08%   26004.146514    25869.934363       0.52%     3323    446   4070    123958    93.4s

There are several ways to estimate the size of a Branch-and-Bound tree during running time, see here for instance.
I wanted to know which method HiGHS use to determine this size and searched thoroughly in their documentation page and could not manage to determine how they estimate it. Apart from looking at the solver's code, how could I know which method they use?
You can answer this question for any combinatorial optimization solver that display this information if you prefer to answer for another one different than HiGHS.

I suggest looking at the following paper by Hendel et al.: Estimating the Size of Branch-and-Bound Trees. I believe this is the method used in the SCIP solver. Further, you have a repository here with some of the code. I don't know how up to date it is, though.

@J.Dionisio, two months after your relevant comment, maybe you could write an answer based on it? :)

I'm not sure what is happening in HiGHS, as my C++ is pretty basic, but you can check on the repo for the code. I believe treeweight is what you're after. Link to repo.
For a slightly more complete answer, I can tell you that SCIP's completion percentage is based on Gregor Hendel's et al. paper Estimating the Size of Branch-and-Bound Trees. It has a repo on GitHub (here). It presents a bunch of different measures and then incorporates them into a random forest. Haven't read the paper, but it seems understandable from a cursory glance. It's not being developed right now, but I don't think SCIP has done much more than this.
